# Creating C++ graphic user interface: What is the easiest way to do it?

Tags: c++, user-interface

So it is my understand that using the MFCs, one can created a GUI for a windows application. But is it easier to use use the Qt package instead? Qt is what I'd use for writing an application that runs on linux but for windows I wonder if using the Windows MFCs would be less difficult and time consuming.

Comment: Go with Qt, it's easier to write with than MFC.

Comment: I think you should post some links in an answer to the poor guy @iced :)

Comment: Nobody really uses MFC much anymore.

Comment: @HericDenis don't think he needs any links, he does know about Qt already (and, I assume, used it) but, apparently, never touched MFC (lucky!).

Comment: If your developing on windows and want something quick then MFC. There is a bigger learning curve to using Qt.

Comment: @ahenderson I disagree - compare a "Hello World" program in MFC and in QT for example. Also, MFC gets significantly harder when you want to do more complex stuff with it, since you must then learn how the underlying WinAPI works.

Answer (score 4):

Since you say "Qt is what I'd use... on linux" it sounds like you're already familiar with Qt.  In that case I'd definitely recommend Qt over MFC.  (Hey, that way you can write your application for both platforms!)

Comment: Is MFC still alive? I reckon it was a very brain damaging technology.

Comment: @VladLazarenko ... and always has been.

Comment: I wonder why this question was closed so fast as it was totally constructive and legit. However, I'm stickin' with Qt. The hell with MFC!

Answer (score 1):

If you're already comfortable using Qt, then stick with it - it's cross platform so it will work fine on Windows. Unless you have a specific reason to, there's no point restricting your application to a single platform (and learning a whole new framework) when you are already familiar with a cross platform one.

Additionally, MFC is a lot harder to work with than Qt. Although it was designed to be an Object Oriented layer on top of WinAPI, it wasn't done particularly well IMO and you still need to be comfortable with WinAPI if you want to be proficient with MFC. The out-of-box widgets are fairly dated and limited in their configurable options, and modifying them or designing new ones is not particularly easy. Being an out of date technology, it is also difficult to find resources and/or support online for when you get stuck.

If you do have your heart set on MFC, you may also want to take a look at wxWidgets - it has a similar "feel" to MFC but is more up to date and cross-platform. Personally I prefer Qt.

Qt can be quite heavyweight, both in terms of implementation (lots of DLL dependencies if you link dynamically) and in terms of building (it adds extra steps to your build process). If your application is more suited to something lightweight (but also more basic in it's functionality), take a look at FLTK.

Comment: My organization also tried wxWidgets, but ended up struggling with it and switched to Qt.  I was not working on the project during that time, so have only used Qt, but have found it quite easy to work with. (Yes, the extra compilation step is tedious, but we put up with it for all the other benefits that Qt provides.)  (Also, we are a Windows-only shop.)